# using squashfs image file as rootfs

Tags: filesystems, embedded-linux, yocto, mount, squashfs

I'm working on a system where I wish to use a squashfs image as the root file system. What I would like to do is have a kernel image and a squashfs image file in an ext4 partition to facilitate upgrading with RAUC.

Is it possible to get the kernel image to mount a squashfs image and use that for the rootfs? If so can someone please point me to some instructions for how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Adrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to create your own initramfs that mount the ext4 partition, find the squashfs image and mount it in `/mnt/image`, then use `switch_root` provided by `busybox` to switch to using `/mnt/image` as `/`.

Comment: Thanks JiaHao Xu. That has given me something to work on. I'll post a follow up comment in due course so other can see how this worked out.